# Angular DevExpress autocomplete issue

Tags: javascript, angular, devexpress

Ive just started with learning DevExpress after coming from Primeng.I am currently having issues with the the dev express grid

```
 <dxi-item dataField="VehicleRegistration">

                      <dx-autocomplete
                            *dxTemplate
                            [(value)]="this.selectedVehicle"
                            [showClearButton]="true"
                            [placeholder]="autoCompletePlaceholderText"
                            [dataSource]="vehicleOptions"
                            hint="Type to search"
                            (onValueChanged)="searchVehicleRegistration($event)">
                      </dx-autocomplete>

                        <dxi-validation-rule type="required" message="Vehicle Registration is required"></dxi-validation-rule>
                      </dxi-item>
```

When I populate vehicleOptions then select my an Item from that list it doesnt save in the grid on (OnRowUpdate). is there something I am missing here?
I asked  on the forum of devexpress but the couldnt help me as I am not registered on the system and would need to pay to be assisted.

I tried
`<dxi-item dataField="VehicleRegistration"  editorType="dxAutoComplete" [editorOptions]="{ dataSource: vehicleOptions }"> </dxi-item>`
that didnt work at all